# ruby on rails create loop inside currentSlide(1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, loops

I have here these pictures in the gallery to be as slides.
How can i replace the number here to be continue like 1 then 2 then 3 for each image
onclick: "openModal();currentSlide(1)"

here is my codes

```
  <% @galleries.each do |g| %>
    <% if g.image1.present? %>
      <div class="column <%= g.product_name %>">
        <div class="content">
          
            <%= image_tag g.image1.url,alt: "conversion", style: "width:100%", onclick: "openModal();currentSlide(1)" ,class: "hover-shadow cursor"%>
          
        </div>
      </div>
      <% end %>
  <% if g.image2.present? %>
    <div class="column <%= g.product_name %>">
    <div class="content">
      
        <%= image_tag g.image2.url,alt: "conversion", style: "width:100%", onclick: "openModal();currentSlide(2)" ,class: "hover-shadow cursor"%>
    
    </div>
  </div>
  <% end %>
  <% if g.image3.present? %>
    <div class="column <%= g.product_name %>">
    <div class="content">
      
        <%= image_tag g.image3.url,alt: "conversion", style: "width:100%", onclick: "openModal();currentSlide(3)" ,class: "hover-shadow cursor"%>
      
    </div>
  </div>
  <% end %>
  <% if g.image4.present? %>
    <div class="column <%= g.product_name %>">
    <div class="content">
      
        <%= image_tag g.image4.url,alt: "conversion", style: "width:100%", onclick: "openModal();currentSlide(4)" ,class: "hover-shadow cursor"%>
      
    </div>
  </div>
  <% end %>
  <% if g.image5.present? %>
    <div class="column <%= g.product_name %>">
    <div class="content">
        <%= image_tag g.image5.url,alt: "conversion", style: "width:100%", onclick: "openModal();currentSlide(5)" ,class: "hover-shadow cursor"%>
    
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: what is image1, image2, image3 ?

Comment: @Vishal inside gallery model theres 5 images I named them image 1, image 2 ... image 5

Answer (score 1):

When you find yourself using names like `image1`, `image2`, `image3`, `image4`, `image5` (with numbers at the end) you should stop and think: can I turn these five things into one array?

If you change your gallery model to have an array `images` you
could then use a loop:

```
<% @galleries.each do |g| %>
  <% g.images.each_with_index do |image, i| %>
    <div class="column <%= g.product_name %>">
      <div class="content">
          <%= image_tag image.url, alt: "conversion", 
                style: "width:100%", 
                onclick: "openModal();currentSlide(#{i})",
                class: "hover-shadow cursor"%>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

You already know the `each` loop.  `each_with_index` is quite
similar when looping across an array, but it also gives you the index. The first index is 0.